# TRESTRequest: How to add an array as the body of a PUT request

Tags: json, delphi, rest

I want to send a PUT request where the body contains an array of JSON objects, like this:

```
PUT http://hostname/api/items
[{"ID":1},{"ID":2},...]
```

Using code like the following, I can easily send a POST request with a single TJSONObject in the body:

```
req := TRESTRequest.Create(nil);
req.Client := FRESTClient;
req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
req.Resource := 'api/items';
req.AddBody(someJSONObject);
req.Execute;
```

Fiddler shows the request as having the correct content:

```
{"ID",1}
```

However, if I use a PUT request and add a TJSONArray as the body instead...

```
ja := TJSONArray.Create;
for jo in someJSONObjects do
  ja.Add(jo);
req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPUT;
req.AddBody(ja);
```

Fiddler shows the request as having a huge pile of bizarre JSON content:

```
{"elements":{"items":[{"members":{"items":[{"jsonString":{"strBuffer":{"data":["I","D","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],"length":2,"maxCapacity":2147483647},"owned":true},"jsonValue":{"strBuffer":{"data":["1","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""],"length":1,"maxCapacity":2147483647},"owned":true},"owned":true}],...
```

It looks like some kind of low-level serialization of the raw in-memory object, instead of the expected JSON array contents.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddBody) on the AddBody method is not very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question...

The overloads of the AddBody method include:

```
procedure AddBody(AObject: TJSONObject);
procedure AddBody<T>(AObject: T);
```

I had assumed TJSONArray was derived from TJSONObject and would therefore use the first overload, but in fact both classes derive from TJSONValue. Therefore, the TJSONObject overload was not used in my case, but rather the generic  overload, which apparently succeeded at some kind of lower-level serialization.

Since there is no direct overload for TJSONArray, and the API I'm using doesn't expect a JSON array wrapped in an object, I did this instead:

```
req.AddBody(ja.ToJSON, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
```

This serializes the array to a string, and then specifies the content type as `application/json`.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH for posting the answer to your question. Helped me out a lot!